# Azure AD authentication via REST to an AAD enterprise App

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, adal, adal4j

I am using ADAL4j to attempt to authenticate to our onprem sharepoint instance (which itself is using AAD to authenticate as an enterprise app) to authenticate users when coming in through the standard flow.

I have set up my consumer AAD app to require the permission to "access {on prem sharepoint enterprise app}". I am then making a request to a url that looks like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
                      response_type=code&scope=user_impersonation&
                      response_mode=form_post&
                      redirect_uri={uri that is registered in my app}&
                      client_id={my app id}&
                      resource={onprem sharepoint enterprise app id}&
                      state={GUID}&nonce={GUID}
```

The response I receive is 401 UNAUTHORIZED:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Invalid audience Uri '{onprem sharepoint enterprise app id}'."
}
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here? My searches have not been very fruitful and logically it seems like it should work. Is there some setting on the enterprise app side of things to allow certain clients to access the resource?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you added the sharepoint resource in your apps `Permissions` it's requesting access for? Can be done in the Azure portal in the `settings` blade.

Comment: Yes. in the application (called search-api) I have enabled access to the sharepoint onprem resource. Is there another step after adding this?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YGopHn2

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `resource={onprem sharepoint enterprise app id}` with the `App ID URI of onprem sharepoint enterprise app` (secured resource). For the details, you could refer to the [Oauth 2.0 grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code).

Comment: Still seems like the same result: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid audience Uri 'urn:sharepoint:{hostname of onprem sharepoint}'."}  Will take a better look at the page linked to see if I can find any holes.

Comment: For the new error, you should check your hostname of onprem sharepoint to make sure the correct name.

Comment: I have confirmed that the URN matches the hostname of the onprem sharepoint

Comment: @Anthony, could you replace the resource value with `https://graph.windows.net`. And then you try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Sunny. After doing that, I am getting the following errors:
2018-09-19 11:04:47 DEBUG wire:86 - http-outgoing-1 << "{"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. Could not resolve issuer token."}"
2018-09-19 11:04:47 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
2018-09-19 11:04:47 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-1 << Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
2018-09-19 11:04:47 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-1 << x-ms-diagnostics: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"

Comment: I find a [blog](http://aurramu.blogspot.com/2015/04/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-during.html), maybe you can refer to it to have a try. Hope it can help you.